# Fluent Validation and ASP.NET Core 6 Web API

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0, fluentvalidation

I am new to fluent validation and also a beginner in Web API. I have been working on a dummy project to learn and your advice will be much appreciated. After following the FluentValidation website, I was able to successfully implement fluent validation.

However, my response body looks very different and contains a lot of information. Is it possible to have a regular response body with validation errors?

I will put down the steps I took to implement fluent validation. your advice and help are much appreciated. I am using manual validation because based on the fluent validation website they are not supporting the auto validation anymore.

In the program file, I added

```
builder.Services.AddValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<CityValidator>();
```

Then I added a class that validated my `City` class which has two properties `Name` and `Description`:

```
public class CityValidator : AbstractValidator<City>
{
    public CityValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Name)
                .NotNull()
                .NotEmpty()
                .WithMessage("Please specify a name");
        RuleFor(x => x.Description)
                .NotNull()
                .NotEmpty()
                .WithMessage("Please specify a Description");
    }
}
```

In my `CitiesController` constructor I injected `Validator<City> validator`; and in my action, I am using this code:

```
ValidationResult result = await _validator.ValidateAsync(city);

if (!result.IsValid)
{
    result.AddToModelState(this.ModelState);
    return BadRequest(result);
}
```

The `AddToModelState` is an extension method

```
public static void AddToModelState(this ValidationResult result, ModelStateDictionary modelState)
{
    if (!result.IsValid)
    {
        foreach (var error in result.Errors)
        {
            modelState.AddModelError(error.PropertyName, error.ErrorMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

On post, I am getting the response as

```
{
    "isValid": false,
    "errors": [
        {
            "propertyName": "Name",
            "errorMessage": "Please specify a name",
            "attemptedValue": "",
            "customState": null,
            "severity": 0,
            "errorCode": "NotEmptyValidator",
            "formattedMessagePlaceholderValues": {
                "PropertyName": "Name",
                "PropertyValue": ""
            }
        },
        {
            "propertyName": "Description",
            "errorMessage": "Please specify a name",
            "attemptedValue": "",
            "customState": null,
            "severity": 0,
            "errorCode": "NotEmptyValidator",
            "formattedMessagePlaceholderValues": {
                "PropertyName": "Description",
                "PropertyValue": ""
            }
        }
    ],
    "ruleSetsExecuted": [
        "default"
    ]
}
```

While the regular response without Fluent Validation looks like this:

```
{
    "errors": {
        "": [
            "A non-empty request body is required."
        ],
        "pointofInterest": [
            "The pointofInterest field is required."
        ]
    },
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId": "00-1a68c87bda2ffb8de50b7d2888b32d02-94d30c7679aec10b-00"
}
```

The question: is there a way from the use the fluent validation and get the response format like

```
{
    "errors": {
            "": [
                "A non-empty request body is required."
            ],
            "pointofInterest": [
                "The pointofInterest field is required."
            ]
        },
        "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
        "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
        "status": 400,
        "traceId": "00-1a68c87bda2ffb8de50b7d2888b32d02-94d30c7679aec10b-00"
    }
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I have updated my ans for manual validation. please check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated ans:

with your code, you can simply replace.

```
 return BadRequest(result); // replace this line with below line.
 return ValidationProblem(ModelState);
```

then you get same format as required.

[image]

------------------------*----------------------------------------

Please ignore this for manual validation.

You don't need explicit validation call.

this code is not required:

```
ValidationResult result = await _validator.ValidateAsync(city);

if (!result.IsValid)
{
    result.AddToModelState(this.ModelState);
    return BadRequest(result);
}
```

it will auto validate the model using your custom validator.

you simply need this

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
   return BadRequest(ModelState);
}
```

and it will give you errors in the require format.

Comment: I used you code as   ValidationResult result = await _validator.ValidateAsync(city);
            if (!result.IsValid)
            {
                //result.AddToModelState(this.ModelState);
                return BadRequest(result);
            } However, I still get the same formart

Comment: if (!result.IsValid)
            {
                //result.AddToModelState(this.ModelState);
                return BadRequest();
            } and this will return no validation error comment

Comment: if (!result.IsValid)
            {
                result.AddToModelState(this.ModelState);
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }  this will return {
    "Name": [
        "Please specify a name"
    ],
    "Description": [
        "Please specify a name"
    ]
} but then the type, title and status is missing

Comment: I think you misunderstood the ans, you also need to remove `ValidationResult result = await _validator.ValidateAsync(city);` and only keep code what I have written.

Comment: First Thank you for your help. It seems you are using Auto validation which is not recommended. I am using manual validation.

Comment: "not recommended", from where you have got this I would also like to know more about this. the whole point of using fluent validation is that you don't need to inject validators around the whole code and not need to repeat validation code everywhere.

Comment: Please refer to this link : https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/aspnet.html#automatic-validation

Comment: this is new for me. thanks for sharing the link..

Comment: Awesome it worked as expected. Why the Badrequest() did not work. Maybe the Badrequest(ModelState) would be a good option for production? since it does not provide that much info. This is in documentation "(If you were writing an API controller, then you’d probably return either a ValidationProblemDetails or BadRequest instead of a view result)" correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I have another question. When we use NotFound() we get the response in JSON Format. However, when we pass a NotFound($"The Id = {cityUd}") is not found we get the a string value. Is there possibility to send data inside not found and still getting the original error format? Thanks

Comment: I am happy that it helped. you can mark as accepted ans if it solves your issue. for the NotFound issue I need to check. I would suggest to open a new issue so that you get response from other also.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if(!result.IsValid)
{
        result.AddToModelState(this.ModelState);
        return ValidationProblem(ModelState);
}
```

[image: Errors]